# Check if record exists before creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, if-statement, controller

I have a subscribe method in my controller

```
  def subscribe

    @subscription = current_user.subscriptions.create(params[:subscription])
    @subscription.title = @stream.title
    @subscription.save

    redirect_to stream_path(@stream)

  end
```

Before I set the subscription title to the stream title, how can I check if a subscription already exists with the same title?

Comment: Create a unique index on title. Then if `save!` fails, the record exists.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  ie MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite etc?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: @SergioTulentsev could you help me with the save! fails method? If the record already exists and I call the method again, it adds a blank entry to the database

Answer (score 0):

Like so :

```
current_user.subscriptions.where(title: @stream.title).present?
```

But assuming you only want to save it if it *is not included elsewhere* you can do this :

```
if current_user.subscriptions.where(title: @stream.title).blank?
  @subscription.title = @stream.title
  @subscription.save
end
```

An elegant way to perform this is to add the logic to your controller so that it validates uniqueness ( and also prevents race conditions ) :

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates_uniqueness_of :title, scope: :user
end
```

And then you can check validation in model.save ( again, assuming you don't want it to save if it shares the same title )

Comment: This is susceptible to race conditions, ie another one being saved in between it being tested and saved.  @Sergio's db-level validation is better.

Comment: That's not db-level, it's rails-level.  It's effectively the same as your previous answer.  db-level would be a database-level validation (eg in a BEFORE UPDATE trigger) or an index.

Answer (score 0):

To help you out, the suggestion by `@Sergio Tulentsev` basically means you create a unique index on a column in your db, like this:

```
#db/migrate/[timestamp]_new_migration.rb
add_index :table, :column, unique: true
```

This creates an [index on your data table](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index), which basically means you cannot make any duplicate data in it. The bottom line - it means you can only insert the data once.

--

The [`save!`](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveRecord/Base/save!) method is there to update your record if it exists already. First time I've seen this method, so it's been a good lesson for me. If you're having problems with it, it will probably be that your database will not have the `index` you need

Comment: It's true that `save!` "updates your record if it exists already", but normal `save` does that also.  The difference between `save!` and `save` is that if it fails to save (because of failed validation), `save!` raises an exception while `save` simply returns `false`.

Comment: Your answer was a long time ago, but is this considered good practise? It feels like more of a hack to rely on a failed attempt rather than determining if the record exists first, but I can't quite determine why